# Execute jQuery function on load and change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select field in a form, and wish to execute some jQuery when the field is changed or when the page is reloaded on form submit.

```
<select name="emp_status_id" class="emp-status-id" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Full-Time Employment</option>
    <option value="2">Part-Time Employment</option>
    <option value="3">Casual</option>
    <option value="4">Self Employed</option>
</select>
```

My jQuery is below

```
function employmentGroups(id){ 
    var emp_status_id = id.val();
    // Do more stuff here
};

$( ".emp-status-id" ).change(function() {
    employmentGroups($(this));
});
```

Not: I am passing $(this) into the function rather than getting $(this) inside the function for another reason which isn't relevant to the current question.

This works perfectly well on change.

I would also like to execute the function on page load,

My problem is that I do not understand which jQuery method to use to execute this function on load.

I have tried this...

```
$( ".emp-status-id" ).ready(function() {
    employmentGroups($(this));
});
```

However this does not work.

Comment: <strike>what do you mean `load`. Are you referring create, or changing value ?</strike> oh i get it `$(document).ready(function(){
employmentGroups($( ".emp-status-id" ));
})` try this

Comment: It's a real shame you can't do `$('.emp-status-id').on('load change', function() { ... });` – but you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function(){ employmentGroups($( ".emp-status-id" )); })`

Looking for this?

Answer (score 2):

Better way to access this selectbox value by id.
Here is working code:

```
<select id="emp_status_id" name="emp_status_id" class="emp-status-id" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Full-Time Employment</option>
    <option value="2">Part-Time Employment</option>
    <option value="3">Casual</option>
    <option value="4">Self Employed</option>
</select>

function employmentGroups(selector_id){ 
    var emp_status_id = $(selector_id).val();
    // Do more stuff here
};

// on page loaded
$(function() {

    // set onchange handler       
    $("#emp-status-id").change(function() {
        employmentGroups('#emp-status-id');
    });

    // just execute 
    employmentGroups('#emp-status-id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there's two ways to do such a thing like this

1- using `load()` but this will fire whatever the code inside every time page reload even when the use open the page for the first time

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // do whatever you want
});
```

2- using built-in `PerformanceNavigation` interface ... i didn't test such a case to use it but it exactly for detecting navigation behavior

```
if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
  console.log('page reloaded');
}
```

or (is the same as above but with different syntax)

```
if (performance.navigation.type === PerformanceNavigation.TYPE_RELOAD){
  console.log('page reloaded');
}
```

for further reading [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#performancenavigation)  and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation)